# Pattern for scripts that should only update when in trigger range

Tags: unity, c#, performance, monobehaviour

I have a script that triggers when the enemies are in range of my objective, but it also contains an Update method for its the damage.

I noticed that Update is being called even when the enemies are not in range of the objective.

I am wondering if it's worth it to have the triggers and Update code in separate scripts, then turn off/on the scripts when entering or leaving the triggers. Or is there a better pattern to use for this kind of setup?

Comment: Do you experience already lagging or other problems? Don't overcomplicate it, if there is no perceived problem, just first focus on your game. IF you experience some kind of fps or lag problems, it is likely not from this. But to be sure, always include the code in your question

Comment: When the update method and the OnTrigger* methods don't have anything to do with each other, then I would advocate to put them into different scripts to enforce the Single Responsibility Principle. Each script should only be concerned with one game mechanic. Btu that's not a performance concern but a software architecture concern.

Comment: The performance question isn't possible to answer with the limited information contained in the question. Have you run your game in the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html)? Do you notice a significant load from the Update function of that particular MonoBehaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the trigger and update code to be written in separate scripts. Collision messages like `OnTriggerEnter/Exit` will be called even on disabled MonoBehaviours, to give you the option to wake them up in response.

So this for example:

```
public class TriggerWatcher : MonoBehaviour {

    int _collidersOverlapped = 0;

    void Start() {
        enabled = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        _collidersOverlapped++;
        enabled = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        _collidersOverlapped--;
        enabled = _collidersOverlapped > 0;
    }

    void Update() {
        Debug.Log("tick");
    }
}
```

...will only "tick" on frames where there's at least one collider overlapping it.

If you have just one object overlapping this trigger at a time, you can also use `OnTriggerStay(Collider other)`, which will be called once each physics step for each collider that previously called `OnTriggerEnter` and has not yet called `OnTriggerExit`. But note this can be more than once per display frame.

You can even call `OnTriggerEnter` as a coroutine by writing `IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter`, to start some continuous action each time a trigger crosses in - but this will have some allocation cost compared to using the built-in methods.

As for "is it worth it", as pointed out in the comments, only [profiling your game](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) will tell you whether you are paying a significant cost with your current setup, and whether you gain any significant savings from alternatives.

While it's tempting to think that one way must just be faster or slower, this can actually depend a lot on the specifics of your game. Even an ostensibly "slower" way to do things as judged on paper can be just as fast or even faster in some circumstances, if it's making use of resources that were otherwise sitting idle due to another bottleneck.

Always measure before you burn time on "optimizations" that might not have a discernible impact on your game / on your target hardware.